# Handle empty strings as image paths when using gatsby-transformer-sharp

Tags: gatsby

I am using Gatsby with Netlify CMS. I use gatsby-transformer-sharp for various image manipulations.

In Netlify CMS, if a user deletes an image, the frontmatter value becomes an empty string, e.g:

**my-blog-post.md:**

```
---
image: ''
---
```

This causes gatsby-transformer-sharp to error, when I am querying Graphql:

```
Error Field "image" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields.
```

This seems to be because Gatsby/Graphql has inferred the image field to be a string.

So I created a `schema.md` file, so there will always be at least one entry with a valid image in place:

**_schema.md:**

```
---
image: /some-dummy-image.jpg
---
```

Which seems to partially fix the problem - the build only fails occasionally. But it *does* still fail. I think it must infer its schema from the first markdown file it comes across - sometimes it finds `_schema.md` first, sometimes it finds `my-blog-post.md` first.

Has anyone managed to find a solution to this?

Comment: So far no, but it looks like something is coming -- for now everyone's using a hidden dummy post (that got filtered out in queries)... [you can see the discussion here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3344)

Comment: Thanks - I am already using the 'dummy post' method (I called it `_schema.md`). The problem is that this sometimes fails. Sometimes Gatsby will incorrectly infer the `image` field to be a string (because `my-blog-post.md` contains `image: ''`). I'm not sure how Gatsby decides *which* file to use when it infers the schema. I put an underscore in my dummy post filename so it would come first alphabetically when read from the file system, but still it doesn't always work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this in the end. I didn't realise that it was actually easy to directly remove these empty fields from frontmatter, before the schema is inferred.

I made a little custom plugin that would recursively go through frontmatter fields, and any fields that had an empty string are deleted. I also only allowed it to delete fields with a specific name (e.g: `image`) so it wouldnt cause unexpected changes elsewhere.

**src/plugins/remove-empty-fields/gatsby-node.js:**

```
let fieldsToRemove = [];

const deleteFieldsRecursive = (node) => {
  fieldsToRemove.forEach(fieldToRemove => {
    if (node[fieldToRemove] === '') {
      delete node[fieldToRemove];
    }
  });

  if (typeof node === 'object') {
    Object.values(node).forEach(subNode => {
      deleteFieldsRecursive(subNode);
    })
  }
};

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node }, configOptions) => {
  fieldsToRemove = configOptions.fieldsToRemove;

  if (node.internal.type === 'MarkdownRemark') {
    if (!node.frontmatter) {
      return;
    }

    deleteFieldsRecursive(node);

  }
};
```

Then added this to the plugins list in `gatsby-config.js`

```
{
  resolve: 'remove-empty-fields',
  options: {
    fieldsToRemove: [
      'image',
      'bgImage',
    ],
  },
},
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

Since Gatsby@^2.2.0, the best way to handle this error is to use the Gatsby hook `createSchemaCustomization`. We need to tell Gatsby that the `image` field will definitely be a file.

```js
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.createType(`
    type RemarkFrontmatter @infer {
      image: File
    }

    type MarkdownRemark implements Node @infer {
      frontmatter: RemarkFrontmatter
    }
  `)
}
```

- [Docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/)

---

**Old answer**

I've recently learned that you can modify a markdown's frontmatter directly before its `MarkdownRemark` node is even created, and come back here to share.

`gatsby-transformer-remark` use `graymatter` to parse frontmatter & allows users to pass in a custom parser. Internally, graymatter use `js-yaml`.

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');

const customParser = (str) => {
  const result = yaml.safeLoad(str);

  // remove image (non recursively, as an example)
  const { image, ...withoutImage } = result;

  return withoutImage;
}
```

And pass it into `gatsby-transformer-remark`

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
  options: {
    engines: {
      yaml: customParser,
    },
}
```

Syntactically, I prefer the way you do it -- it's clearer when the empty fields are handled by a plugin. Just wanna add another option!